# Thymeleaf onclick Unexpected identifier javascript

Tags: javascript, spring-boot, thymeleaf

I cannot figure out how to get this Thymeleaf code to work properly. I am recieving an unexpected identifier for the th:onclick function:

```
th:onclick="'addBadge('badgeListTwy', \'' + ${taxiway.getId()} + '\', \'' + ${taxiway.getName()} + '\');'"
```

This is part of a drop down list that I'm trying to populate for a button using th:each

```
<ul class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenuLink">
    <li  th:each="taxiway : ${taxiways}">
        <a class="dropdown-item" href="#" th:onclick="'addBadge('badgeListTwy', \'' + ${taxiway.getId()} + '\', \'' + ${taxiway.getName()} + '\');'"><span th:text="${taxiway.getName()}"></span></a>
    </li>
</ul>
```

This gives me an 'Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier' error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best way to do this is to store arguments in data attributes, like this:

```
<ul class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenuLink">
    <li th:each="taxiway : ${taxiways}">
        <a class="dropdown-item" href="#"
            th:data-id="${taxiway.id}"
            th:data-name="${taxiway.name}"
            onclick="addBadge('badgeListTwy', this.getAttribute('data-id'), this.getAttribute('data-name'));"><span th:text="${taxiway.getName()}"></span></a>
    </li>
</ul>
```

It simplifies the quoting, and removes certain JavaScript vulnerabilities.  (Notice I'm using `onclick` instead of `th:onclick`.)

That being said the original expression probably isn't working becuase you didn't escape the quotes around `'badgeListTwy'`